# push attribute data to trie, add to multiple keys

Tags: c++, recursion, trie

my knowledge is limited but I have been working (hacking) at this specific data structure for awhile

I use a trie to store ontology strings that are then returned as a stack including the 'gap' proximity when get (string) is called. As an add on the trie stores attributes on the key. The further down the string the greater the detail of the attribute. This is working well for my purposes.

As an additional add on, I use a wildcard to apply an attribute to all child nodes. For example, to add 'paws' to all subnodes of 'mammals.dogs.' I push(mammals.dogs.*.paws). Now, all dogs have paws.

The problem is only the first dog get paws. The function works for push attributes without wild

If you want I can clean this up and give a simplified version, but in the past i've found on stackoverflow it is better to just give the code; I use 'z' as the '*' wild

```
void Trie::push(ParseT & packet)
{
    if (root==NULL) AddFirstNode(); // condition 1: no nodes exist, should this be in wrapper
    const string codeSoFar=packet.ID;
    AddRecord(root, packet, codeSoFar); //condotion 2: nodes exist
}

void Trie::AddFirstNode(){ // run-once, initial condition of first node
    nodeT *tempNode=new nodeT;
    tempNode->attributes.planType=0;
    tempNode->attributes.begin = 0;
    tempNode->attributes.end = 0;
    tempNode->attributes.alt_end = 0;
    root=tempNode;
}



//add record to trie with mutal recursion through InsertNode
//record is entered to trie one char at a time, char is removed
//from record and function repeats until record is Null
void Trie::AddRecord(nodeT *w, ParseT &packet, string codeSoFar)
{
    if (codeSoFar.empty()) {

        //copy predecessor vector at level n, overwrites higher level vectors
        if (!packet.predecessorTemp.empty())
            w->attributes.predecessorTemp = packet.predecessorTemp;

        return;  //condition 0: record's last char
    }
    else { //keep parsing down record path

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < w->alpha.size(); i++) {
            if (codeSoFar[0] == w->alpha[i].token_char || codeSoFar[0] == 'z') {
                return AddRecord(w->alpha[i].next, packet, codeSoFar.substr(1)); // condition 2: char exists
            }
        }
        InsertNode(w, packet, codeSoFar); //condition 3: no existing char --> mutal recursion
    }
}

//AddRecord() helper function
void Trie::InsertNode(nodeT *w, ParseT &packet, string codeSoFar) // add new char to vector array
{
    for (unsigned int i=0; i <=w->alpha.size(); i++) { // loop and insert tokens in sorted vector
        if (i==w->alpha.size() || codeSoFar[0] < w->alpha[i].token_char) { //look for end of vector or indexical position

            //create new TokenT
            tokenT *tempChar=new tokenT;
            tempChar->next=NULL;
            tempChar->token_char=codeSoFar[0];

            //create new nodeT
            nodeT *tempLeaf=new nodeT;
            tempLeaf->attributes.begin = 0;
            tempLeaf->attributes.end = 0;
            tempLeaf->attributes.planType = 0;
            tempLeaf->attributes.alt_end = 0;

            //last node
            if (codeSoFar.size() == 1){

                tempLeaf->attributes.predecessorTemp = packet.predecessorTemp;
            }

            //link TokenT with its nodeT
            tempChar->next=tempLeaf;
            AddRecord(tempLeaf, packet, codeSoFar.substr(1)); //mutual recursion --> add next char in record, if last char AddRecord will terminate

            w->alpha.insert(w->alpha.begin()+i, *tempChar); 
            return; 
        }
    }
}

root is global nodeT *w

    struct ParseT {

        string ID; //XML key

        int begin = 0; //planned or actual start date
        int end = 0; //planned or actual end date - if end is empty then assumed started but not compelted and flag with 9999 and 
        int alt_end = 0; //in case of started without completion 9999 case, then this holds expected end
        int planType = 0; //actuals == 1, forecast == 2, planned == 3

        map<string, string> aux;

        vector<string> resourceTemp;
        vector<string> predecessorTemp;
    };
```

[image: This is what I'd like it to do]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code

```
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < w->alpha.size(); i++) {
        if (codeSoFar[0] == w->alpha[i].token_char || codeSoFar[0] == 'z') {
            return AddRecord(w->alpha[i].next, packet, codeSoFar.substr(1)); // condition 2: char exists
        }
    }
```

you are returning as soon as you call `AddRecord`, even if it is because of a wildcard. It might be easier to have a separate loop when `codeSoFar[0] == 'z'` that goes through all the alphas and adds the record. Then have an else clause that does your current code.

Edit: Here is what I meant, in code form:

```
else { //keep parsing down record path
    // Handle wildcards
    if (codeSoFar[0] == 'z') {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < w->alpha.size(); i++) {
            AddRecord(w->alpha[i].next, packet, codeSoFar.substr(1)); // condition 2: char exists
        }
    }
    else {
        // Not a wildcard, look for a match
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < w->alpha.size(); i++) {
            if (codeSoFar[0] == w->alpha[i].token_char) {
                return AddRecord(w->alpha[i].next, packet, codeSoFar.substr(1)); // condition 2: char exists
            }
        }
        InsertNode(w, packet, codeSoFar); //condition 3: no existing char --> mutal recursion
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it does, because a single path only needs to call AddRecord once at each level. Your wildcard handler will need to call AddRecord for each `w->alpha`, rather than return after the first one.

Comment: I am testing your suggestion now, and my intuition was that it had something to do with the return statement. But, it also seems like the return will break when it passes through AddRecord() without return - yes? This is what I see: return AddRecord() --> return AddRecord() --> return AddRecord() AddRecord()  missing the rest of the return AddRecord() path?

Comment: AddRecord doesn't actually return anything, so your don't have to return the result of AddRecord. You do need to make sure that you don't fall through and call InsertNode after you have finished with the wildcard loop. Let me know if it still isn't clear and I will update my answer with some code.

Comment: I tried with a separate for loop just for the wild case AddRecord()  with an else to the non-wild case return AddRecord(). But, the wild is not working. I also tried removing the return from the code I posted, but then it eventually crashed during the Insert loop. I cannot visualize the return, stack, recursion paths and were they are breaking. I do see what you mean by return AddRecord() preventing the for loop from going any further than once.

Comment: that is exactly what I have  - it works. It worked last time but the output file had the results spread throughout the file, so I just saw the same two entries that were there before. There was 6k entries before, now there are 21k. Thank you.